# Unable to run iOS app on iOS 15 Simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, visual-studio-2022

I do not have a iPhone 13 and need to debug my app on iOS 15.4 as apparently there's a screen resolution issue or some other issue which causes the app's screen to be bigger than the phone screen.  The app runs fine on my test device, an iPhone 6, but obviously its a tad out of date.  The app crashes immediately when the simulator attempts to run it.  The error I get is:

[image: Error message]

I think this may be a permission issue, no?  Not sure as the only feature the app uses, other than the internet, is the camera and the permission is set in info.plist.  Any suggestions?

******* UPDATE: Added Simulator Log

```
Startup:
    arguments: --device=27495837-1C30-49ED-B814-DC14E7112DB8 --launchsim=//Users/prescottchartier/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/iOSPhotoManager/d4a378afae087127b50d68ae980e92c7568732fc756e3455147359d52176d94a/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/iOSPhotoManager.app -argument=-monodevelop-port -argument=53149 -setenv=__XAMARIN_DEBUG_PORT__=53149 --sdkroot=/Applications/Xcode.app -h=192.168.1.8 -ssh=prescottchartier 
    version: 17.3.0.471 (97213889733ed3f399d3574c2f4f20e614e9dc7a)
Connection state changed:
    State: Connecting
SSH Connect:
    target: 192.168.1.8
Using SSH pass phrase
SSH connected
Connection state changed:
    State: SshConnected
Connection state changed:
    State: CheckingServer
Connection state changed:
    State: SettingUpServer
Starting server
[Server] ready:50593
Connection state changed:
    State: Connecting
Connection state changed:
    State: CheckingServer
Connection state changed:
    State: Connected
Start device request:
    Current State: Unknown
    UUID: 27495837-1C30-49ED-B814-DC14E7112DB8
    Name: iPhone 13
    Platform: iOS
    Version: 15.5
Device state changed:
    UUID: 27495837-1C30-49ED-B814-DC14E7112DB8
    State: Starting
Device state changed:
    UUID: 27495837-1C30-49ED-B814-DC14E7112DB8
    State: Started
SizeForScreen:
    Monitor: 0,0,1366,728
    Scale: 1,1
    Source: 1170,2532
    extraHeight: 84
Warning: App failed to install+launch
System.Exception: Could not launch the app 'com.CGAssociates.PhotoManager' on the device 'iOS 15.5 (19F70) - iPhone 13': simctl returned exit code 3
   at Xamarin.Simulator.Core.Protocol.SimulatorClient.<InstallAndLaunchRemoteAppAsync>d__26.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.Simulator.Windows.App.<HandleApp>d__19.MoveNext()
    ErrorCode: 0

    Device: 27495837-1C30-49ED-B814-DC14E7112DB8
    Path: //Users/prescottchartier/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/iOSPhotoManager/d4a378afae087127b50d68ae980e92c7568732fc756e3455147359d52176d94a/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/iOSPhotoManager.app
    Arguments: -argument=-monodevelop-port -argument=53149 -setenv=__XAMARIN_DEBUG_PORT__=53149 
Connection state changed:
    State: Disconnected
Connection state changed:
    State: Connecting
SSH Connect:
    target: 192.168.1.8
Using SSH pass phrase
SSH connected
Connection state changed:
    State: SshConnected
Connection state changed:
    State: CheckingServer
Connection state changed:
    State: SettingUpServer
Starting server
[Server] ready:50634
Connection state changed:
    State: Connecting
Connection state changed:
    State: CheckingServer
Connection state changed:
    State: Connected
Device state changed:
    UUID: 27495837-1C30-49ED-B814-DC14E7112DB8
    State: Starting
Device state changed:
    UUID: 27495837-1C30-49ED-B814-DC14E7112DB8
    State: Started
```

Comment: What happens if you open the project directly in VS for Mac and build and deploy there?

Comment: Same thing, app immediately crashes.

Comment: If you run a blank xcode project on same simulator, does that work?

Comment: Blank app runs fine.

Comment: So I think in order to help you more, you need to provide some more information. Some logs would help. Dig into the device log and see if you can figure out what is going wrong launching the App.

Comment: Added Simulator log to question.

Comment: No you need to look in the device log of the simulator to see why it fails to start the App.

Comment: There are no simulator device logs that I can find, these are the only logs that I can find that are connected to the simulator.  If you are aware of others I'd sure like to know where they are.

Comment: Open the Console App, select your simulator and observe when attempting to install

Comment: I see nothing called "console app" in VS 2022 iOS debugging, if you could detail how I would do that I would appreciate it.  Thanks.

Comment: It is a macOS app..

Comment: Ah ... I run Windows VS 2022

Comment: If you are using a simulator, you have a connected Mac. You need to open the Console.app on that connected Mac and select the running simulator. That is the only way to see simulator logs.